# Osquery how to run select command?

Tags: osquery

I installed osquery on my Kali Linux 2019.3 (VirtualBox VM) via using this link: https://osquery.io/downloads/official/4.3.0 (I picked debian)

I tried to run select  comond, nothing happens. Only apperas `...>`

For example when I tried `select* from listening_port` againg nothing happens. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I  found the my mistake, I forgat use **";"** after code. For example it must be `select * from listening_ports;`